# How do I change the limit on the number of entities return for a WCF Data Service?

Tags: wcf-data-services

I've noticed that no matter what query I issue against a WCF Data Service, I only ever get 25 rows back. How can I modify either the client or the service to allow all to come back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own the service then this is totally up to you. If you don't own the service and the author wanted it this way, there's no way for you to change this (which is good, security feature).

If you get only 25 and the request doesn't fail (and you're sure there's more than 25) then you should also see a next link in the response (at the very end), which points to the next 25 and so on.

On the server this is usually setup by calling config.SetEntitySetPageSize method in the InitializeService.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I took on supporting an application and didn't realize where in the initialization code the previous developer placed a setting for SetEntitySetPageSize. Thanks!